# What happens to the outDir in tsconfig.json for Angular projects?

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I have added Angular to my Node Express app in VS Code. I did this through Angular CLI's `ng new`.

In `tsconfig.json`, `outDir` points to `./dist/out-tsc`.  There is another `outDir` in `angular-cli.json`.

When I run `ng build`, Javascript files are generated in the `outDir` indicated in `angular-cli.json`.  What is the `outDir` in `tsconfig.json` for? The folder `./dist/out-tsc` was not created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the outDir in tsconfig.json for?

Nothing if using AngularCLI. The `angular.json` (`.angular-cli.json` prior to Angular 6) file controls the output configuration.

As indicated by:

> The folder ./dist/out-tsc was not created.

If you use VS Code file watchers to compile your TS files on the fly/on request, then the tsconf.json file location will be used (depending on VSCode config of course). You can probably surmise that using one method or the other is a good idea. You may run into versioning difficulty if you use a combination of both methods.

Stick to the CLI.

Comment: Thanks. Where's the instruction/config that disabled the TS actions when AngularCLI is used. Also, how do I have watch mode under such a set up?

Comment: it is part of the WebPack configuration used internally by the AngularCLI. You'll find the WebPack config that changes this in the node_modules folder containing AngularCLI. I can try to find it if you'd like.

Comment: Will appreciate it very much!

Comment: For AngularCLI v1.7.3, you will find the WebPack config in `[PROJECT-ROOT/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js`. Inside that file you'll find the use of `appConfig`. The `appConfig` is pulled from `angular-cli.json`

Comment: I didn't answer the "watch mode question". The answer is `ng serve --open` - watch automatically occurs.